# Python - Write data from list into specific Excel column

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, list, openpyxl

I have a list of data which I want to write into a specific column (B2 column) in Excel

Input example:

```
mydata =[12,13,14,15]
```

Desired Output in Excel:

```
A2| B2| 
  | 12|    
  | 13|
  | 14|
  | 15|
```

I have tried using openpyxl to access the specific sheet (which works fine) and specific cell(B2) but it throws an error to write to the excel file as it is a list. It works fine if I assign a single value as shown in the code extract below:

```
mydata= my_wb['sheet2']['B2'] = 4
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: should every number go into b2? Or b2, b3, b4 and so on?

Comment: yes that's correct b2,b3 etc @ph140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the list and paste each value into the desired row in column B:

```
for i, n in enumerate(mydata):
    my_wb["sheet2"].cell(i+2, 2).value = n
```